# To dual boot Ubuntu with Win7: Do I have to manually make root/home/swap partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I’m trying to set up dual boot for Ubuntu and Win7. My partitions are MBR type, this is how the installation screen looks right now:

---

sda1, ntfs,  104 MB

sda2, ntfs,  254599 MB

free space, 245295 MB

sda3, fat32, 105 MB

Device for boot loader installation:

sda ATA ST500DM002-1BD14 (500.1 GB)

---

Since I’m a complete noob I want to avoid creating the root, home, swap partitions. I’d just like to use the free space as one big partition for Ubuntu. If I just click “Install Now”, will Ubuntu install correctly for dual boot?

Also if I use the current selection for “Device for boot loader installation” is it going to mess up Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not need to make root/home partitions.  When Ubuntu installs will install just as /root.  Ubuntu does not use swap partitions now.  Just make sure you use 'install beside windows' or 'something else' options to install.  The separate /root and /home partitions some people like to have, instead of just one /root partition.  Both choices are okay.  Grub should usually be installed in sda, not a sda partition(like sda1, sda2)

Answer (score 0):

No need! Just select automatic during installation! This will automatically make Home and Root partitions! There is also no need for a swap partition as there is already a swapfile!